# RestExpress - cannot see Infinispan logs

Tags: java, rest, infinispan

I am using Infinispan 7.2.5 embedded in RestExpress 0.10.4. I have deployed my RestExpress application in 3 virtual machines. But I cannot see any infinispan related logs(org.infinispan, org.jboss, org.jgroups).

```
2016-03-07 01:00:42 DEBUG logging:15 - Logging Provider: infinispan.org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
2016-03-07 01:00:42 DEBUG ServiceFinder:61 - Loading service impl: JpaStoreLifecycleManager
2016-03-07 01:00:42 DEBUG ServiceFinder:52 - No service impls found: ModuleMetadataFileFinder
2016-03-07 01:00:42 DEBUG ServiceFinder:52 - No service impls found: ModuleCommandExtensions
2016-03-07 01:00:42 DEBUG ModuleProperties:80 - No module command extensions to load
2016-03-07 01:00:42 DEBUG DefaultCacheManager:631 - Started cache manager test-cluster on null
```

When I just set up Infinispan in 3 virtual machines, it works fine.

```
01:10:55,376 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
01:10:55,741 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
01:10:55,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss Infinispan Server 7.2.5.Final (WildFly 8.2.0.Final) starting
...........
```

My cache configuration as follows.

```
GlobalConfigurationBuilder global = GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder();
global.transport().clusterName("test-cluster");

ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC);

// Initialize the cache manager
DefaultCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(global.build(), builder.build());
```

My log4j configuration as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
        xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

        <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - $
                </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
                <param name="append" value="false" />
                <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
                <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
                <param name="file" value="/var/log/caceh-restservice-test.log" />
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - $
                </layout>
        </appender>

        <logger name="com">
                <level value="INFO" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="org">
                <level value="INFO" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.infinispan">
                <level value="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.jboss">
                <level value="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.xxxxx.test.infinispandistributed">
                <level value="DEBUG" />
        </logger>
        <root>
                <level value="DEBUG" />
                <appender-ref ref="console" />
                <!-- appender-ref ref="file" /-->
        </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer to my own question.

Nodes seems note joining to the cluster or may be cache will not initiated until it's getting the first request.

Once I put a value to the cache, logs generated as expected.

```
2016-03-07 23:53:53 INFO  JGroupsTransport:186 - ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel test-cluster
2016-03-07 23:53:53 WARN  UDP:536 - JGRP000015: the send buffer of socket DatagramSocket was set to 1MB, but the OS only allocated 131.07KB. This might lead to performance problems. Please set your max send buffer in the OS correctly (e.g. net.core.wmem_max on Linux)
2016-03-07 23:53:53 WARN  UDP:548 - JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket DatagramSocket was set to 20MB, but the OS only allocated 131.07KB. This might lead to performance problems. Please set your max receive buffer in the OS correctly (e.g. net.core.rmem_max on Linux)
```

Comment: Yeah, until Infinispan 8.2.0.Beta2 it was necessary to call `getCache` to get global component registry, which manages the JGroups transport, to start. As a result of fixing [ISPN-6214](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-6214) we've changed that, and now creating a cache manager will start it.